# Secure External Network Control of a MQTT Server on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, security

I'm trying to build a home automation system using MQTT. I'm using a Raspberry Pi as the broker. Everything works great as far as controlling it when connected to the same network. But I want to have the functionality of being able to control it from an external network. I don't want to just open a port that anyone can send traffic through. What's the best way to set up external control of the MQTT network securely so only devices that I want can connect and control it?

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: Hi @Nick, which broker are you using on your Pi? Mosquitto?

Comment: A few more ideas for your IoT server: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6mjt8tWUws. In particular PiVPN might be what you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15VjDVCISj0